# Putting someone or something down to bond with others

Tags: single-word-requests

I have seen a behaviour whereby people will criticize or be mean about others in an attempt to bond or find common ground with the person they are speaking to.

Is there a word for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a single word, but...

> [**Outgroup derogation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingroups_and_outgroups#Outgroup_derogation)

is defined in that Wikipedia article as *the phenomenon in which an outgroup is perceived as being threatening to the members of an ingroup.* But obviously the implied response is to **derogate** *([**cause to seem inferior** or be in disrepute](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/derogate), belittle)* those in the outgroup.

As I understand it, the primary purpose of such behaviour is to strengthen the ingroup bonds, rather than to disadvantage the outgroup.

Comment: I agree with your understanding of this. Those I have seen acting in this way are apart of the same in-group as those they are criticising, though I guess their intention is to create or strengthen an inner-in-group